# Display: table-cell on new row

Tags: css

Here is an example code for what I mean:

HTML

```
<ul class="table">
  <li class="table-cell"></li>
  <li class="table-cell"></li>
  <li class="table-cell"></li>
  <li class="table-cell"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Q: How can I make the third and forth `<li>` (table cells) display on new row with width: 50% each?

Q: Is there a way using only CSS and not jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple answer is:  you can't, at least not with lists.  Adjacent elements with their display set to `table-cell` are treated as belonging to the same row (even if a row element is not provided, an anonymous one will be created for you).  Since lists aren't allowed to contain any other tags between the ul and the li, this simply isn't possible with lists.  You'll have to use either different markup or different styling.

Here are your options if you don't want to modify the markup.

Inline-block on the list items:  http://jsfiddle.net/XNq74/1/

```
li {
    display: inline-block; /* could use floats here instead */
    width: 40%;
}
```

CSS columns would be a reasonable choice:  http://jsfiddle.net/XNq74/

```
ul {
    columns: 2;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Flexbox would also work and can be used in combination with inline-block:  http://jsfiddle.net/XNq74/2/

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li {
    flex: 1 1 40%;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: inline-block make a 4 px gap between objects, if i recall right. i need them to be gapless. also the objects at least on the same row must have to be the same height (dynamic height).

Comment: No, whitespace makes a 4px gap between inline-block objects, you can do lots of things to get rid of it (see http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).  Since they must be the same height, flexbox is your man:  http://jsfiddle.net/XNq74/11/

Comment: Thanks for help and resources. Flexbox has a low browser support. For fighting the space between inline block elements, it's a good source. i have only think about -margin. however, this does not solve the same height issue while also keeping a good compatibility with gradients (example for using the -margin +padding and hidden overflow method).

Comment: Without modifying the markup and using pure CSS, flexbox is your only option.  You're the only one who can decide how critical the appearance is to your design, but I would use inline-block/float in combination with flexbox if the grid layout was the most important.  There *is* a polyfill for the old 2009 specification: http://flexiejs.com/ (source: https://github.com/doctyper/flexie)

Answer (score -5):

```
ul.table li+li+li { /** your CSS code **/ } This one is for the third element


ul.table li.last { /** your CSS code **/ }   This one is for the fourth element
```